# Asking User For Datetime Before Plotting Selected Points

Tags: python, datetime, graph

I'm using Python 2.7.3, How can I ask the user to enter "from datetime" & "to   datetime" before plotting the selected criteria onto a graph
   For eg. when user 
   from datetime: 21/7/2014 0:00
   to datetime: 22/7/2014 23:57

```
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
x = []
y = []
t = []
fig = plt.figure()
rect = fig.patch
rect.set_facecolor('#31312e')
readFile = open('data.txt', 'r')
sepFile = readFile.read().split('\n')
readFile.close()
for idx, plotPair in enumerate(sepFile):
    if plotPair in '. ':
        # skip. or space
        continue
    if idx > 1:  # to skip the first line
        xAndY = plotPair.split(',')
        time_string = xAndY[0]
        time_string1 = datetime.strptime(time_string, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
        t.append(time_string1)
        y.append(float(xAndY[1]))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, axisbg='white')
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'))
ax1.plot(t, y, 'c', linewidth=3.3)
plt.title('IRRADIANCE')
plt.xlabel('TIME')
fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=45)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi, I see your question again. You mean ask user to enter two datetime and then put them onto a graph? You don't need data from 'data.txt' now?

Comment: hi thanks:) user will enter from what time to what time 

so for eg. the user will choose 21/7/2014 0:00 to 22/7/2014 23:57

then graph will show just data from 21/7/2014 0:00 to 22/7/2014 23:57

and yes, still using the data from data.txt

Comment: What about `stdat = input("Enter from date (dd/mm/yyyy) ")` and simply parsing input ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
x = []
y = []
t = []
fig = plt.figure()
rect = fig.patch
rect.set_facecolor('#31312e')
readFile = open('C:\\Temp\\001.txt', 'r')
sepFile = readFile.read().split('\n')
readFile.close()

startTime = raw_input('please enter start time in format like 21/7/2014 0:00 :')
endTime   = raw_input('please enter end time in format like 22/7/2014 23:57 :') 

# startTime = '21/7/2014 0:02'
# endTime = '22/7/2014 23:58'
startTime = datetime.strptime(startTime, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
endTime = datetime.strptime(endTime, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')


for idx, plotPair in enumerate(sepFile):
    if plotPair in '. ':
        # skip. or space
        continue
    if idx > 1:  # to skip the first line
        xAndY = plotPair.split(',')
        time_string = xAndY[0]
        time_string1 = datetime.strptime(time_string, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
        if startTime<=time_string1 <=endTime:
            t.append(time_string1)
            y.append(float(xAndY[1]))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, axisbg='white')
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'))
ax1.plot(t, y, 'c', linewidth=3.3)
plt.title('IRRADIANCE')
plt.xlabel('TIME')
fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=45)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: hi, it works! thank alot:) 
however when i enter for start time: 21/7/2014 0:00
                     for end time  : 21/7/2014 0:05

the graph look very weird

Comment: @toothberry Yeah, then you have to adjust your code. Don't forget confirm it as an answer. :)

Comment: is it possible to ask the user for input on the graph rather than on python shell window?

Comment: @toothberry I don't think there is an easy way to accomplish this.

Comment: but is it do-able? at least for a beginner like me?

Comment: @toothberry  Yes, I believe you can